# Python3 asyncio "Task was destroyed but it is pending" with some specific condition

Tags: python-3.x, coroutine, python-asyncio

Here is simplified code, which uses python3 coroutine and sets handler for SIGING and SIGTERM signals for stopping job properly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import argparse
import asyncio
import signal
import sys


def my_handler(signum, frame):
    print('Stopping')
    asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()
    # Do some staff
    sys.exit()


@asyncio.coroutine
def prob_ip(ip_addr):

    print('Ping ip:%s' % ip_addr)
    proc = yield from asyncio.create_subprocess_exec('ping', '-c', '3', ip_addr)
    ret_code = yield from proc.wait()
    if ret_code != 0:
        print("ip:%s doesn't responding" % ip_addr)
        # Do some staff
        yield from asyncio.sleep(2)
        # Do more staff
        yield from asyncio.sleep(16)


@asyncio.coroutine
def run_probing():

    print('Start probing')
    # Do some staff
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

    while True:
        yield from asyncio.wait([prob_ip('192.168.1.3'), prob_ip('192.168.1.2')])
        yield from asyncio.sleep(60)


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.description = "Probing ip."
    parser.parse_args()

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, my_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, my_handler)

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run_probing())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When i run it via:

```
python3 test1.py
```

It stops by Ctrl-C without any warnings.
But when I run it via:

```
python3 -m test1
```

It prints warning by Ctrl-C:

```
$ python3 -m test1 
Start probing
Ping ip:192.168.1.2
Ping ip:192.168.1.3
PING 192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2): 56 data bytes
PING 192.168.1.3 (192.168.1.3): 56 data bytes
^C--- 192.168.1.2 ping statistics ---
--- 192.168.1.3 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
Stopping
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<prob_ip() running at /tmp/test1.py:22> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]> cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at /usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py:394]>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<prob_ip() running at /tmp/test1.py:22> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]> cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at /usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py:394]>
```

Same warning I get if I install this script via:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='some_scripts',
      version='1.0.0.0',
      author='Some Team',
      author_email='team@team.ru',
      url='https://www.todo.ru',
      description='Some scripts',
      packages=['my_package'],
      entry_points={'console_scripts': [
          'test1=my_package.test1:main',
      ]},
      )
```

My python version is "3.4.2"

Comment: You might want to use [loop.add_signal_handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.add_signal_handler), though it's not related to your problem.

Comment: Yes, thanks, this way looks better in my case. But it doesn't help. I still get same warnings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok. I think I have figured out how should I stop all tasks.

1. First of all, as far as I understand. [BaseEventLoop.stop()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.stop) is only to stop  [BaseEventLoop.run_forever()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_forever). So one should cancel all tasks via [Future.cancel](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future.cancel). To get all tasks you can use [Task.all_tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.all_tasks) static method.
2. After cancellation all tasks asyncio.CancelledError exception will be raised from run_until_complete. So one should catch it, if one doesn't want to print it to stderr.
3. And also, in some cases, I get this error: `TypeError: signal handler must be signal.SIG_IGN, signal.SIG_DFL, or a callable object`.
   I found some topics about this error:

   - https://bugs.python.org/issue23548
   - https://github.com/buildinspace/peru/issues/98

   They all say that it can be fixed by closing loop before exiting application.

So we get this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import asyncio
import signal


def my_handler():
    print('Stopping')
    for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
        task.cancel()


@asyncio.coroutine
def do_some(some_args):
    while True:
        print("Do staff with %s" % some_args)
        yield from asyncio.sleep(2)


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, my_handler)

    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([do_some(1), do_some(2)]))
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print('Tasks has been canceled')
    finally:
        loop.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It works also with [signal.signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.signal). But as Vincent [noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505066/python3-asyncio-task-was-destroyed-but-it-is-pending-with-some-specific-condit#comment54817243_33505066) [loop.add_signal_handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.add_signal_handler) looks better in this case.

But I am still not sure is this the best way to stop all tasks.

Comment: (1) unlike futures, tasks may ignore `.cancel()` (catch `CancelledError`) (2) if tasks need to clean up then you could [`loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*asyncio.Task.all_tasks()))` before `loop.close()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27796294/4279)

Comment: If you don't want the signal handler to cancel all the running tasks, have a look at my answer (edited).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, thank you, i have to wait for unfinished tasks before exit. But (I don't know why) asyncio.gather doesn't work in this case (at list in python3.5.0). asyncio.wait works, so we get such code: https://gist.github.com/willir/b521450b66be6e6b238c.

Edit: Also I don't know why I need not to catch asyncio.CancelledError from this (actually second one) loop.run_until_complete.

Comment: @willir: (1) my guess, you have wrong arguments (`asyncio.wait()` and `asynio.gather()` have different interface e.g., notice `*` in the call above). (2) if you don't understand how/where/when `CancelledError` may be raised when ask a separate question that focuses on it.

Answer (score 8):

Use [asyncio.gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio) instead of `asyncio.wait`:

> Cancellation: if the outer Future is cancelled, all children (that have not completed yet) are also cancelled.

Example:

```
def handler(future, loop):
    future.cancel()
    loop.stop()

@asyncio.coroutine
def do_some(arg):
    while True:
        print("Do stuff with %s" % arg)
        yield from asyncio.sleep(2)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.gather(do_some(1), do_some(2))
loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, handler, future, loop)
loop.run_forever()
```