# Python asyncio gather does not exit after task complete

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a coroutine `foo1` from which I use `asyncio.create_task()` to call another coroutine `foo2`.

As expected, `foo1` finishes running and does not wait for the task to complete because there is no await.

I have added `asyncio.gather()` at the end to finish up any pending tasks.

The problem is `gather` does not release control back to the main program after the task is complete.
How do I get the program to end and run `print("done")` when complete?

```
import asyncio

async def foo3(x):
    for y in range(2):
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print(f"foo3 {x} {y}")

async def foo2():
    for x in range(2):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        asyncio.create_task(foo3(x))
        print(f"foo2 {x}")

async def foo1():
    t = asyncio.create_task(foo2())  # If I await this the code exits prior to completion of nested tasks.
    pending = asyncio.all_tasks()
    await asyncio.gather(*pending)   # This line never finishes even after foo2 & foo3 are complete
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(foo1())
    print("done")
```

```
# Output
foo2 0
foo2 1
foo3 0 0
foo3 1 0
foo3 0 1
foo3 1 1
```

Comment: You create tasks in `foo2`, but never await them? (i.e. `asyncio.create_task(foo3(counter))`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Full answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68629884/13946204)

> but the issue with that can sometimes be an infinite loop where it waits for the asyncio.current_task() to complete, which is itself. Some answers suggested some complicated workarounds involving checking coro names or len(asyncio.all_tasks()), but it turns out it's very simple to do by taking advantage of set operations

- Short answer: you must change one line:

`await asyncio.gather(*pending)` → `await asyncio.gather(*pending - {asyncio.current_task()})`

```
import asyncio

async def foo2():
    for x in range(3):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        print(x)

async def foo1():
    asyncio.create_task(foo2())
    pending = asyncio.all_tasks()
    await asyncio.gather(*pending - {asyncio.current_task()})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(foo1())
    print("done")
```

```
0
1
2
done
```